# Using A Custom Attribute That Is In A Style With A View

Tags: android, android-layout

Lets say I have a custom attribute in a few styles like so:

```
<style name="Theme1" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="textViewBackground">#000022</item>
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
  </style>
<style name="Theme2" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="textViewBackground">#AA2200</item>
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
  </style>
```

Can I then reference that in a standard view like a TextView? Something like:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@CurrentTheme.textViewBackground"
    android:text="Number" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a TextView style, like this:

```
<style name="Theme1" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/TextViewStyle1</item>
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme2" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/TextViewStyle2</item>
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
</style>

<style name="TextViewStyle1" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:background">#000022</item>
</style>

<style name="TextViewStyle2" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:background">#AA2200</item>
</style>
```

Then you won't even need to set the `android:background` attribute on each `TextView` in your xml, it will apply to all `TextView`s that do not specify a different background.

Comment: I was hoping to have one theme that defines a whole bunch of global variables instead of creating a separate theme for each element. Oh well. Thanks!